# How to validate a bean property in respect of its previous value in JAX-RS/JPA?

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jersey, eclipselink

I'm on Jersey and JPA (EclipseLink) and I have a `Project` entity and a `Status` entity persisted on a database:

```
@Entity
public class Status {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  public String name;

  @OneToMany
  public Set<Status> next;
}

@Entity
public class Project {
  @Id
  public Long id;

  public String title;

  public Status status;
}
```

and the `Project` JAX-RS resource:

```
@Path("/projects")
public class ProjectResource {
  @Inject
  private ProjectDAO dao;

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<Project> getProject() {
    return this.dao.findAll();
  }

  @PUT
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public void putProject(Project project, @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    this.dao.update(project);
  }   
}
```

When a `Project` is updated via `PUT`, I need to check that if its `status` is changed the new value must be contained in the `next` set of the previous one, i.e. something like:

```
public void validateStatus(Status prevStatus, Status nextStatus) {
  if (!prevStatus.contains(nextStatus)) {
    throw new InvalidStatusException();
  }
}
```

I tried with this:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void putProject(Project project, @PathParam("id") Long id) {
  Project current = this.dao.find(id);
  this.validateStatus(current.status, project.status);
  this.dao.update(project);
}
```

but since the unmarshalled `project.status` isn't the same instance of the one retrieved with JPA, the check fails. Of course this works:

```
public void validateStatus(Status prevStatus, Status nextStatus) {
  for (Status status : prevStatus.next) {
    if (status.id == nextStatus.id) {
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new InvalidStatusException();
}
```

but doing so I'm not using Java `Set` capabilities (e.g. `contains`) and it is not applicable on a more generic validation checks between a persisted entity and a request of update.

I'm looking for a better and more generic ways to validate an entity in respect of its previous status.

Comment: Have you implementes `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods on `Status` ? Without this `prevStatus.contains(nextStatus)` will never work indeed..